# Error cased by passing a list via viewBag "Object reference not set"

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I am trying to display a list of Items in the View section in asp.net passed from the controller as follows:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles.ToList(),"Name","Name");

    return View();
}

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Roles, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Roles",null, "Name",new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Group")]
public string Roles { get; set; }
```

However I got the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current  web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error showing this line of code:

```
Line 143:            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles.ToList(),"Name","Name");

public void CreateRoles()
{
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
    IdentityRole role;

    if(!roleManager.RoleExists("Admins"))
    {
        role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Admins";
        roleManager.Create(role);
    }
}
```

Additional details upon the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ASP.Identity.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: I have updated the database also

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Roles",(<SelectList>)ViewBag["Roles"], "Name",new { @class = "form-control" })
```